# Do any crypto exchanges still use traditional market making?

Tags: cryptocurrency, order-execution, market-making

Do crypto trading platforms or DEXs still use traditional market making schemes? Or are there no more traditional market makers out there, only automated market makers that utilize smart contracts?

Comment: I think it depends on the scenario. A wild guess in ETH would be a bit of both. Smart contracts are running the show.

Comment: Most traditional crypto exchanges use the order book model, most but not all DEXs use the automated market maker model (some also use order books). In any case, this is definitely not an opinion-based question, because one could write a well-sourced answer discussing the order fulfillment schemes that these exchanges use.

Comment: Thanks, are there different types of nonautomated market maker? I’ve heard of contractual and non contractual but couldn’t really understand the difference…

Comment: And also I’ve heard of market makers that work as kind of an agent, and also orders from market makers that won’t be on the order book and won’t be registered on footprint chart after the execution… I’m so confused as there are so many informations saying different random things….